# I can't get Grunt Source Maps to work in foundation-press theme

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, zurb-foundation

I am having difficulty getting source maps to work for npm package grunt-sass.

Here is my Gruntfile.js

This is the part that is not working  `sourceMap: true,` line 13

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var jsApp = [
    'js/app.js',
    'js/_*.js'
  ];

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),


      sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                'css/app.css': 'scss/app.scss'
                }
            }
        },


    autoprefixer: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                'css/app.css': 'css/app.css'
            }
        },
      watch: {
          styles: {
              files: ['css/app.css'],
              tasks: ['autoprefixer']
          }
        }
      },

    copy: {
      scripts: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/',
        src: '**/*.js',
        dest: 'js'
      },

      maps: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/',
        src: '**/*.map',
        dest: 'js'
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'js/modernizr/modernizr.min.js': ['js/modernizr/modernizr.js']
        }
      }
    },

    concat: {
      options: {

        separator: ';'
      },
    dist: {
        src: [
          'js/foundation/js/foundation.min.js',
          'js/custom/*.js'
        ],

        dest: 'js/app.js'
      }

    }



  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass']);



};
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "grunt-sass",
  "version": "0.8.1",
  "description": "Compile SCSS to CSS using node-sass",
  "keywords": [
    "gruntplugin",
    "css",
    "sass",
    "scss",
    "style",
    "compile",
    "preprocess"
  ],
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass/issues"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "Sindre Sorhus",
    "email": "sindresorhus@gmail.com",
    "url": "http://sindresorhus.com"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-sass": "~0.7.0",
    "async": "~0.2.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.2.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "licenses": {
    "type": "MIT"
  },
  "files": [
    "tasks/sass.js"
  ],
  "_id": "grunt-sass@0.8.1",
  "dist": {
    "shasum": "694a0fe351af3466079e138b2c70afe2f46a5618",
    "tarball": "http://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-sass/-/grunt-sass-0.8.1.tgz"
  },
  "_from": "grunt-sass@>=0.8.0 <0.9.0",
  "_npmVersion": "1.3.14",
  "_npmUser": {
    "name": "sindresorhus",
    "email": "sindresorhus@gmail.com"
  },
  "maintainers": [
    {
      "name": "sindresorhus",
      "email": "sindresorhus@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "directories": {},
  "_shasum": "694a0fe351af3466079e138b2c70afe2f46a5618",
  "_resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-sass/-/grunt-sass-0.8.1.tgz"
}
```

[image: Node Modules Installed]

Answer (score 0):

Please use the official `grunt-contrib-sass` package. You can find it here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass

Once installed and loaded you can do something like this:

```
sass: {
  options: {
    sourcemap: true,
    style: 'compressed'
  },

  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'css/scss',
      src: ['*.scss'],
      dest: './css',
      ext: '.css'
    }]
  }
}
```

Make sure to load it with:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
```